# I am seeing Lord Narayana in everything. What does this mean?

Tags: vishnu

I am seeing lord Narayana in everything in my daily life. In every particle, in every tree , in every person who I see, in every animal, in every leaf, in every flower, in every food dish, in every computer in my office, in every building, on every road, in every vehicle, everywhere its as if Lord Narayana is everything. What does this mean ?

Comment: If this is indeed true, you are blessed. Please rush to a true guru. I recommend visiting Sringeri Jagadguru Mahaswami. Also these are intensely personal experiences and must not be shared with the world openly. I recommend that you delete your question here and reserve your questions for the true guru.

Comment: If this is true, you are really blessed. Very rare jivas get this oppurtunity. Go to true Guru and tell him your experiences. It's not even difficult to get a guru for you. Your Guru will guide you further.

Comment: It means your previous life karma is giving you this realization of the truth....narayana parambramhan just seek his refuge and he will liberate you BG 18.66 http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/. The essence of Purusha sukta is what you are experiencing  `namostwanataya sahasramurtayae sahasrapadakshisirorubahave shasranamne purushaya shashwate sahasra koti yugadharine namaha`

Comment: Try to ask Lord Narayana "Who are you?" (I mean try to concentrate).

Answer (score 5):

> **I am seeing Lord Narayana is everything. What does this mean ?**

I too agree with the views expressed by users in the comments section that indeed "You are very fortunate and a blessed person, as you have achieved the state of the mind which is very difficult to achieve, while we are mentally involved in our family life.

I have found some shlokas from **Shreemad Bhagvad Gita** as well as **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana**, where lord himself is describing your state of mind.

> Bhagvad Gita -:
>
> तानि सर्वाणि संयम्य युक्त आसीत मत्पर: । 
>  वशे हि यस्येन्द्रीयाणि
>   तस्य प्रज्ञा प्रतिष्ठिता ॥६१॥
>
> tāni sarvāṇi saṁyamya yukta āsīta mat-paraḥ 
>  vaśe hi yasyendriyāṇi
>   tasya prajñā pratiṣṭhitā
>
> One who restrains his senses, keeping them under full control, and
>   ﬁxes his consciousness upon Me, **is known as a man of steady
>   intelligence.** [**BG 2.61**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/61)
>
> ---
>
> तदबुद्धयस्तदात्मानस्तन्निष्ठास्तत्परायणाः। 
> गच्छन्त्यपुनरावृत्तिं
>   ज्ञाननिर्धूतकल्मषाः ॥१७॥
>
> tad-buddhayas tad-ātmānas tan-niṣṭhās tat-parāyaṇāḥ 
>  gacchanty
>   apunar-āvṛttiṁ jñāna-nirdhūta-kalmaṣāḥ
>
> When one’s intelligence, mind, faith and refuge are all ﬁxed in the
>   Supreme, then one becomes fully cleansed of misgivings through
>   complete knowledge and thus **proceeds straight on the path of
>   liberation.** [**BG 5.17**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/5/17)

And here is what Bhagvat purana says -:

> इति सर्वाणि भूतानि मद्भावेन महाद्युते । 
>  सभाजयन मन्यमानो ज्ञानं
>   केवलमाश्रित: ॥१३॥
>
> iti sarvāṇi bhūtāni mad-bhāvena mahā-dyute 
>  sabhājayan manyamāno
>   jñānaṁ kevalam āśritaḥ
>
> O brilliant Uddhava, one who thus views **all living entities with the**
>   idea that I am present within each of them, and who by taking shelter
>   of this divine knowledge offers due respect to everyone, **is
>   considered actually wise.** (True knower). [**SB 11.29.13**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/29/13-14)
>
> ---
>
> अयं हि सर्वकल्पानां सध्रीचीनो मतो मम । 
>  मद्भाव: सर्वभूतेषु
>   मनोवाक्कायवृत्तिभि: ॥१९॥
>
> ayaṁ hi sarva-kalpānāṁ sadhrīcīno mato mama 
>  mad-bhāvaḥ
>   sarva-bhūteṣu mano-vāk-kāya-vṛttibhiḥ
>
> Indeed, I consider this process — using one’s mind, words and bodily
>   functions for realizing Me within all living beings — to be the best
>   possible method of **spiritual enlightenment.** [**SB 11.29.19**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/29/19)

So from analysing above shlokas we can say that your current state is of **Gyani** who have realised  god in everything.
And proceeding towards final goal i.e. Moksha.

Comment: Narayana itself means Indweller so seeing Indweller in all is truly divine vision!

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing Nārāyana everywhere `outside` is not a final accomplishment, (to see `inside` is,) rather it is a sort of **divine** welcome by Lord to you for journey to the ultimate `Vasudeva tattva`. (This is a descent of Shakti), You should intensely dive into spirituality & devotion to Lord Nārāyana, now material world should be of no use to you other than a play where you have to complete your play without any material desires. It seems Lord saying to you these words -

> Just think of Me, be My devotee, worship Me, offer obeisance unto Me; certainly you will come to Me, I promise this in truth to you being dear to Me. BG-18.65.

Also,

> Concentrate the mind upon Me, apply spiritual intelligence for Me; verily you will reside with I after this existence without doubt. BG-12.8.

This is **not the end**, **Highest step** yet to achieve from where there is no return. As also said in the Chāndogya Upanishad.

> When a man’s mind is his reins, intellect, his charioteer; He reaches the **end of the road**, That highest step of **Vishnu**. Valli 3.9.